# open access 2010 report in asp.net aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, report, ms-access-2010

one of my co-workers has Microsoft Access(2010) on his computer and he created some reports.

I want to `display` those reports ouput in my asp.net `aspx` page.

is it possible ?

is there any Microsoft's web component for display access report ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Windows SharePoint Services

> > "Windows SharePoint Services is a feature of Windows Server that lets you store data and deploy database forms and reports over the Web. You can link Access 2007 to Windows SharePoint Services lists, or deploy your whole database to a server and use the collaboration tools that Windows SharePoint Services provides."

For access 2007 you can use a [Data Access Page.](http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/ss/dataaccess.htm)

For more [check](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/what-happened-to-data-access-pages-HA010030832.aspx)

Comment: , Ive tried with DataAccess Page over googl and the only thing for me ( 2007 ) is to export the report to html or other format. but i need the report to be executed at the SAME TIME the report is runnuing. any help ?